# Sum on Listview Item in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I Have Listview That Display in the Image. But now I Want to Sum of Amount column Double Value And show in One TextView below the ListView. so how to perform this operation.

[image]

Adapter code :

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_casehistory, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cqty);
            holder.rate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crate);
            holder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.camount);  

holder.qty.setText(dataItems.get(position).GetQtyName()); 

     holder.rate.setText(dataItems.get(position).GetRateName());
        holder.amount.setText(dataItems.get(position).GetAmountName());               


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }


        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView qty;
        TextView rate;
        TextView amount;

    }
```

Comment: Loop over the Adapter of the ListView and sum the data

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry I forget to write I have update it wait.

Comment: @cricket_007 I update it.

Comment: @cricket_007 see the update.

Comment: And what difficulties have you had writing a method in the adapter class to return the sum of  `dataItems.get(position).GetAmountName()`?

Comment: I want sum of that Amount . so how to perform that .

Comment: Have you tried looping over `dataItems` and doing `total += Double.parseDouble(dataItems.get(position).GetAmountName())`?

Comment: Ohhh I got it My Problem. I try ParseInt but I forget I have used Double Value.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for Help.

Comment: See, if you just included that code initially in your post, I wouldn't have asked so many questions

Comment: @cricket_007 First I write loop but not work then check with parseDouble as you suggest as it work like charm.

Comment: That's fine. Future reference - don't be afraid to post code that didn't work the way you wanted it to

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks again

Answer (score 5):

try this sample code:

```
public double getTotal(ArrayList<YourItem> list){

    double total=0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        total=total+Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).getAmount());
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Looks good other than the data in the question are string values, not double

Answer (score -1):

I think you can handler the Sum of Amount in adapter, and getCount() should be +1, and last item you can show the Sum of Amount. do you show some code for you about your question?

Answer (score -2):

How you are supplying values to the ListView?

if it is an Adapter .. like

```
listview.setAdapter(new customAdapter(context,qty[],rate[],total[])),
```

Then

```
textView.setText(string.valueOf(total[0]+total[1]))
```

Comment: Please format code using code blocks and try not to guess at any code that isn't provided because it may be completely different than what exists

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion . I am new to stackoverflow ...so i will follow this hereafter.