# How to Sum Value in ListView on Android Studio?

Tags: android, json

I am trying JSON Parse in Android. I can parse values but I have a problem. For example, I use this [JSON](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ed2e2a394e2b449598f6d2a17557d8cc).

I made this function:

```
 if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray person = jsonObj.getJSONArray("person ");

                for (int i = 0; i < person .length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = person .getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name= c.getString("name");
                    String age= c.getString("age");



                    HashMap<String, String> persons = new HashMap<>();

                    persons .put("id", id);
                    persons .put("name", name);
                    persons .put("age", age);

                    personList.add(persons);
```

And use for display my screen:

```
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Mainlayout.this, personList,
                R.layout.person_list, new String[]{"name", "age"},
                new int[]{
                R.id.name,R.id.age});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I can see all data in my ListView but I want to sum the ages. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097776/sum-on-listview-item-in-android) on StackOverflow but I can't understand. How can I sum them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply U can use below code as U are able to parse the JSON value :)

Just Declare a variable globally and use this for summation

```
private int sumOfAge = 0;
private int ageValue;

if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            JSONArray person = jsonObj.getJSONArray("person ");

            for (int i = 0; i < person .length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = person .getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String name= c.getString("name");
                String age= c.getString("age");

                ageValue = Integer.parseInt(age);
                sumOfAge+=ageValue;


                HashMap<String, String> persons = new HashMap<>();

                persons .put("id", id);
                persons .put("name", name);
                persons .put("age", age);

                personList.add(persons);
```

Comment: sumOfAge is your desired value

Comment: Thank you, now i use it but my app crashing. I use for display;                        TVTotalMiktar.setText(String.valueOf(sumOfAge));

Comment: then plz try with TVTotalMiktar.setText(sumOfAge.toString());

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like

```
int totalAge = 0;
if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray person = jsonObj.getJSONArray("person ");

                for (int i = 0; i < person .length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = person .getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name= c.getString("name");
                    String age= c.getString("age");


                    totalAge = totalAge + Integer.ParseInt(age);
                    HashMap<String, String> persons = new HashMap<>();

                    persons .put("id", id);
                    persons .put("name", name);
                    persons .put("age", age);

                    personList.add(persons);
```

`totalAge` gives you sum of age.